# how change colors to printable colors in printer and how save canvas context in jpg cmyk?

Tags: javascript, ruby, canvas, rgb, cmyk

I am establishing an online graphical app with html5 canvas and javascript.

The images which are made by this app will be send to printing office.

**problem 1:**

Now Printery ask me a jpg image which in colors written in cmyk form.

All of colors in monitor are rgb form.
As a research I do because all of rgb colors doesn’t exist in cmyk gamut and vice-versa , When a customer choose a color , i should check that whether it exists in printable colors group or not and if it didn‘t exist , i should turn it to the most closest printable color.

For example in photoshop when we choose color rgb(40,61,230) , because it isn’t printable in cmyk color gamut in printer , it turns to color rgb(66,86,166)  for our usage that is close to choosen color and also printable .
Then photshop for this function use **ICC Profiles** , like : **US web coated swop V2**

I downloaded this ICC Profile but it is usable for windows and c# , not for web and javascript.

Now whether there is a plugin for php or javascript from which we could use ICC Profiles?

**EDIT:** I found simple ICC parser api in ruby language:

http://rubygems.org/gems/icc_parser

http://rubydoc.info/gems/icc_parser/0.1/frames

but I dont know about ruby. can someone translate it to php or javascript ??

**problem 2:**

at the end when I want to save the photo and send it to the printing office , it should be in jpeg cmyk form . I save the photo by this code:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
```

But HTML5 canvans  saved the photo like jpeg RGB not CMYK , How should I save photo in form of cmyk and add to it icc profile?

please dont introduce me apies in other programming language !!!

Answer (score 0):

### 1.

For JavaScript unfortunately no. I was in fact just recently investigating this myself and ended up with the ICC specs from the int. color consortium's web site to build my own ICC parser. There are source code out for C/C++ that you can use as basis. For me the project is too big at the moment as I'm involved in other things, but here you'll find all resources that you need to built a parser in JavaScript:

**[ICC official site](http://www.color.org/icc_specs2.xalter)**

Comments though: The print should be able to receive RGB based files and use their print calibrated profile to convert it to CMYK. This is usually better as it will fit their machines better than a general ICC profile. Just a though..

### 2.

You can't. Canvas only support RGB color space. You will have to create a JPEG saver to convert RGB into CMYK (and that after building the ICC parser).

These are non-trivial tasks, that's for sure - they can be done, but it's not a week-end project...

Comment: thanks. I have downloaded [Specification ICC.1:2010-12 (Profile version 4.3.0.0)](http://www.color.org/specification/ICC1v43_2010-12.pdf) from icc site. but its very complex and I cant understand it well !! :(

Comment: @saeidezzati yeah, it can seem a bit overwhelming at first. I did find [this source code in C](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/lcms-1.18/jpegicc/iccjpeg.c) (as you probably know is the foundation for JavaScript syntax-wise) which reads (extracts) an ICC profile from a JPEG file. Perhaps a good start if you plan to dive into it all. I would assume the PDF.js project would have ICC integration - might be worth to take a look at their source code.